# Google drive permissions taking time to update

Tags: google-drive-api

After copying a file with a service account, I add a permission of "writer" to a user in the same domain to the copied file and redirect the user to the file's resource "alternateLink".
since a few days ago the user gets the following message "You need permission"
This happens consistently.
refreshing the page grants access to the file.

Is there any way to insure the file is ready for editing by the user before redirecting them? I tried to get the file again with the user's authorization and check it is editable, but that only results in false positives.

Edit: the problem is no longer consistent, I will try suggested answers as if and when it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your Drive account might take some time to process the calls from the API. With that said, you can rely on the following methods to verify the user's permissions:

You can rely on the "list" function of Drive API, for the Permissions resource.
Within the response from the API, there is the "Items" property, which in turn will show the detailed information about the users for a particular file.
You can find more information in the following reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list

If you have access to the user's account, then you could rely on the "Files" resource, using the "get" method for a particular file.
Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Answer (score 0):

One solution that i implemented is setting some safe amount of delay , say 30 seconds using timertask